# How to interpret the spectogram from spek

Tags: compression, spectrogram

I compressed the wave file to MP3 in two bitrates. How to interpret spectrogram results?

WAV:
[image]

MP3 320 kb/s:
[image]

MP3 128 kb/s:
[image]

Comment: What information are you looking to get? Maybe you can be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The only information I could possibly garner from those three spectrograms is that it's a reasonable possibility that the WAV wasn't the original source file.
There's evidence it has already had a hard low-pass filter or cut-off applied at 15.5KHz.

I suppose the other thing you could guess from it is it's likely a modern hi-gain track, possibly a dance or pop track, potentially a victim of the loudness war. It shows remarkable lack of variation through most of its duration. You can almost see the ear fatigue;)

This is not really conclusive of anything, though. Spectrographs really don't tell you what things sound like & only show up glaring errors or anomolies, they have no real 'fine detail'.
People seem to rely on them too much, as if you could tell from one what process it had been through, or 'how good it should sound'. They really don't work like that.
You can sometimes see evidence of 'bit-filling' as shadowy echoes of lower freaquencies if someone made a poor attempt to claim they're high quality 96KHz, but there's nothing I can see along those lines.